# Why making shell script background does not work as expected

Tags: java, linux, shell, nohup

For example, I was trying to start a java process
in background and ignoring `SIGHUP`.

The first way I tried is to write a shell script like

**start.sh**:

```
java -jar *.jar
```

and execute

```
nohup ./start.sh &
```

the process starts, but does not work as expected.

Another way I try is to direct execute `nohup java -jar *.jar &` in command line, which works well.

So I want to know what's the real difference that makes the first way not work as expected.

Comment: Do not use three asterics, one is enough. `java -jar *.jar`. Also, where are your jars located?

Comment: @Alex jar is located in the same dir as start.sh

Comment: Does start.sh has executable bit set? Does it start without nohup?

Comment: If start.sh does not work then make it executable with `chmod +x start.sh`

Comment: @Alex when executing `./start.sh` directly the process works well in frontground.

Comment: "but does not work as expected" … can you clarify? What do you expect? What is actually happening?

Comment: @knittl I use a client to send http request to that java application, but has no response.

Comment: @scottxiao if you need a server that keeps on running maybe you should make it into a service and start it via systemd

Comment: Does `./start.sh &` work ?